# Show context menu for table header and get column index?

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible to show a context menu on the header of table column and get the index of the selected column?

I have been having a problem return the index of the selected column in a table.

- `table.getSelectionIndex()` returns `-1`
- `Point point = new Point(event.x, event.y)` returns **point {0, 0}**

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Showing a right click menu for a SWT Table header to get the column name or index.

`SWT.MenuDetect` : Sent when the platform-dependent trigger for showing a menu item is detected.

```
table.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect,new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            Point ptAbsolute = new Point(e.x, e.y);
            Point pt = table.toControl(ptAbsolute); 
            int colIndex = columnAtPoint(table, pt);
            if (colIndex >= 0) {
                if (pt.y < table.getHeaderHeight())  {  
                    // Negative Y means table header

                    System.out.println("Column name is " + table.getColumn(colIndex).getText());
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("Row right-clicked on column name is " + table.getColumn(colIndex).getText());
                }
            }
        }
});
```

Class `Point` : A point representing a location in (x,y) coordinate space, specified in integer precision.

```
private static int columnAtPoint(Table table, Point pt) {
    int colIndex = -1;

    TableItem fakeRow = new TableItem(table, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        Rectangle rec = fakeRow.getBounds(i);
        if ((pt.x > rec.x)  && (pt.x < (rec.x + rec.width))) {
            colIndex = i;
        }
    }
    fakeRow.dispose();
    return colIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code that'll print the clicked `TableColumn` header:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.NONE);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE).setText("Column " + i);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            item.setText(i, "Cell " + j + " " + i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }

    table.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, e ->
    {
        Point pt = Display.getCurrent().map(null, table, new Point(e.x, e.y));
        Rectangle clientArea = table.getClientArea();
        boolean headerClicked = (clientArea.y <= pt.y && pt.y < (clientArea.y + table.getHeaderHeight()));

        if (headerClicked)
        {
            int xOffset = 0;
            for (int colIdx : table.getColumnOrder())
            {
                int colWidth = table.getColumn(colIdx).getWidth();

                if (xOffset <= pt.x && pt.x < (xOffset + colWidth))
                {
                    System.out.println(table.getColumn(colIdx).getText());    // Your code goes here
                    break;
                }
                xOffset += colWidth;
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Use `colIdx` if you need the index.

Comment: your code is limited..large column name to get only visible column name but scrollbar to scroll column name not proper work(get column name)..me post this code useful...thanks Baz